# Добавление всех программ в панель управления

Tags: windows

Я сбрасывал все настройки Винды, но без удаления файлов. И столкнулся с тем, что на моем втором диске были установлены программы, я их запустить могу, но стоит мне зайти в панель управления: "Удаление программ", там нет ни одной программы. Есть какой-нибудь способ, чтобы их туда добавить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте в параметрах посмотреть, там есть возможность показать программы со всех дисков

Comment: Неа не смог найти

Comment: А какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Ну во первых чтобы видеть весь список программ, а во вторых из-за того, что система не видит, эти программы, я не могу сделать какую либо программу по умолчанию. К примеру программа для просмотра видео файлов